# Oracle database connection in drupal 7

Tags: database

I want to retrieve a list of products from an external oracle database and show it in my drupal site as a catalog.
But the problem is that, how can I make the connection to oracle db from a drupal 7 site.
Please any suggestion on how to perform this operation is highly welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend separate this from Drupal. I mean if you just want a list of products so write an external application to prepare a xml format of this list and feed it to Drupal.

You need install [PHP PDO_OCI](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php) to make connection from PHP application into Oracle.

Drupal has an [Oracle Driver](http://drupal.org/project/oracle) but I recommend external application instead

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, not did it only help me to solve my problem but by using xml file I have taken away my Dbase online.Something I knew that was not secure to connect the production dbase online but was trying to find out an efficient solution...

Comment: So you need web service which you have authentication rules